# Cannot find 'audio_example.mp3' when using deezer/spleeter

Tags: linux, docker

After installing [Spleeter](https://github.com/deezer/spleeter) in Docker, I tried to run the example `docker run -v $(pwd)/output:/output researchdeezer/spleeter separate -i audio_example.mp3 -o /output`  in Ubuntu as the [doc](https://github.com/deezer/spleeter/wiki/2.-Getting-started#using-docker-image) shows.

But the terminal returned `audio_example.mp3: No such file or directory`.

```
lzq@lzq-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK:~$ docker run -v $(pwd)/output:/output researchdeezer/spleeter separate -i audio_example.mp3 -o /output
ERROR:spleeter:An error occurs with ffprobe (see ffprobe output below)

ffprobe version 4.1.4-1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
audio_example.mp3: No such file or directory
```

Actually there is 'audio_example.mp3' in `$(pwd)`. I tried to copy the mp3 file to `$(pwd)/output` but it still did not work.

Is it an issue about the root permission? Or Docker cannot find the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a directory `input` and place there your file. Then run the following:

```sh
docker run \
  -v $(pwd)/output:/output \
  -v $(pwd)/input:/input \
  researchdeezer/spleeter separate -i /input/audio_example.mp3 -o /output
```

The command is running inside the container so you need to place the file in the container first and then pass to the command a path inside the container.

Comment: Many Thanks!!! It works! I did forget that I also needed to mount a input folder.